# Receive function failing when using msg.value to update state variable

Tags: solidity

I have one function in my contract which purpose is to send all funds to a second contract.

```
   function fundOtherContract() external payable onlyOwner {
            payable(otherContractAddress).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

Then, my other contract has following to successfully retrieve funds sent to it:

```
    receive() external payable {
        require(stateVariable[currentId].status == Status.Open);
        stateVariable[currentId].amount += msg.value; //Here is where it fails
        
    }
```

That currentId is also a state variable.

When calling fund Other I get a gas estimation fee warning and the transaction reverts.

I assume the problem is I cannot access msg.value there?

Is there any way to retrieve the value being being received and store it?

Comment: Are you positive that the require statement in your function isn't failing?

Answer (score 0):

gas is limited to 2700 for transfer and send and they are deprecated.

try

```
(bool ok,) = otherContractAddress.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
require(ok, "transfer failed");
```